# How can i move the vertices of the ROI in python and opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, contour, roi

I trying to draw the contour in the ROI.
But the vertices of the ROI appear on the left side of the image.
I want to move the ROI to the place indicated in the photo, but I don't know how to do it.
I'm new to OpenCV and Python, so any help is much appreciated.
Here is my code.

[image]

```
# Object detected
            center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
            center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
            w = int(detection[2] * width)
            h = int(detection[3] * height)
            # Rectangle coordinates
            x = int(center_x - w / 2)
            y = int(center_y - h / 2)
            boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
            confidences.append(float(confidence))
            class_ids.append(class_id)

indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.4, 0.3)

for i in range(len(boxes)):
    if i in indexes:
        x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
        label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
        confidence = confidences[i]
        color = colors[class_ids[i]]

        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret, img_binary = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 15, 255, 0)
        roi = img_binary[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(roi, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
        print(roi.shape)
        print(x, y, w, h)
```

Comment: The coordinates of your `contours` are inside `box`. So simply shift them by `x` and `y`? Hard to tell without knowing what `boxes` is.

Comment: thank you for your comments.  Boxes is a coordinate of the rectangle. I edit the code. please give me some comments.

Comment: Just shift by `x` and `y`. Give it a try.

Comment: Can I modify this code? "roi = img_binary[y:y+h, x:x+w]"

Comment: The ROI is correct. You have to shift the contours. Two ways to do so. 1. pass `x` and `y` as last argument (`offset`) to `findContours`. The returned `contours` will have coordinates relative to `img_binary`. Or 2. pass `x` and `y` as `offset` to `drawContours`

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but I don't understand the meaning "offset".
Can you explain in detail how to modify the code? Can i modify the code " cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned coordinates of the contours are relative to the ROI passed to `findContours`.
I.e. the `x` coordinates of the contours are relative to the top-left corner of the ROI. Same for `y`.

As you want to display the contours inside of the original image and not inside of the ROI you have to shift them.

There are basically two options:

1. pass `x` and `y` of your ROI to `findContours` like

   ```
   contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(roi, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, offset=(x,y))
   ```

   The returned `contours` will then have coordinates relative to the original image.
2. pass `x` and `y` to `drawContours` like

   ```
   cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3, offset=(x,y))
   ```

   This will leave the coordinates of your `contours` relative to the ROI and just display them inside of the original image.

What makes sense for you depends on your application.

The third option is to manually shift the contours by simply adding `x` to the first dimension and `y` to the second dimension.
The output will be the same as 1.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I've run the code and it works very well.